# dataframe multiply some columns with a series

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe df1 where the index is a DatetimeIndex and there are 5 columns, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5.

I have another df2 which has an almost equal datetimeindex (some days of df1 may be missing from df1), and a single 'Value' column.

I would like to multiply df1 in-place by the Value from df2 when the dates are the same. But not for all columns col1...col5, only col1...col4

I can see it is possible to multiply col1*Value, then col2*Value and so on... and make up a new dataframe to replace df1.

Is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You an achieve this, by reindexing the second dataframe so they are the same shape, and then using the dataframe operator `mul`:

Create two data frames with datetime series. The second one using only business days to make sure we have gaps between the two. Set the dates as indices.

```
import pandas as pd
# first frame
rng1 = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=90, freq='D')
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'value':range(1,91),'date':rng1})
df1.set_index('date', inplace =True)

# second frame with a business day date index
rng2 = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=90, freq='B')
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date':rng2}) 
df2['value_to_multiply'] = range(1-91)
df2.set_index('date', inplace =True)
```

reindex the second frame with the index from the first. Df1 will now have gaps for non-business days filled with the first previous valid observation.

```
# reindex the second dataframe to match the first
df2 =df2.reindex(index= df1.index, method = 'ffill')
```

Multiple df2 by df1['value_to_multiply_by']:

```
# multiple filling nans with 1 to avoid propagating nans
# nans can still exists if there are no valid previous observations such as at the beginning of a dataframe 
df1.mul(df2['value_to_multiply_by'].fillna(1), axis=0)
```

Comment: This is very close to what I need except for 2 things:
1. The data I have in df1 is not constant, and I need to fill the NA with the value each from the previous row.
2. is there a way to do the mul in place?

Comment: reindex has  a paramater called `method` that can be used to fill in gaps in the new index. `'ffill'` takes the last valid observation and `'bfill'` the next valid observation. Updated the code to include it. The data doesn't have to be constant- it was just an example.

Comment: @JBradley Nice answer! I edited your answer so the `df` names match the question. I also think you want to `fillna(1)` before you do the multiplication, instead of doing an `ffill`, right?

Comment: @exp1orer Yes- you are right about the `fillna(1)`. In the example the first two days in the frame were non-business days so there were no valid observations to bring forward to fill them

Comment: Ah, this is a question about the desired behavior -- for a non-business day, does OP just want the value from `df1` or does OP also want to multiply by the interpolated (ffilled) value from `df2`?